# Object destructuring without var, let or const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why does object destructuring throw an error if there is no `var` keyword in front of it?

```
{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

throws `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`

The following three examples work without problems

```
var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2};
var [c, d] = [1, 2];
    [e, f] = [1, 2];
```

Bonus question: Why do we not need a `var` for array destructuring?

I ran into the problem doing something like

```
function () {
  var {a, b} = objectReturningFunction();

  // Now a and b are local variables in the function, right?
  // So why can't I assign values to them?

  {a, b} = objectReturningFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 271, accepted):

The issue stems from the `{...}` operators having multiple meanings in JavaScript.

When `{` appears at the start of a *Statement*, it'll always represent a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which can't be assigned to. If it appears later in the *Statement* as an *Expression*, then it'll represent an Object.

The `var` helps make this distinction, since it can't be followed by a *Statement*, as will [grouping parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping):

```
( {a, b} = objectReturningFunction() );
```

From their docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assignment_separate_from_declaration_2

> Notes: The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2} is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}) is valid, as is var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}
>
> Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

Comment: If it appears later in the Statement as an Expression, then it'll represent an Object. Does this mean we can never have block scope inside grouping parenthesis

Comment: This is a brilliantly obscure bit of knowledge that had me stumped. It allows destructuring across scope (well, sort of -  you still need to declare your variables, of course). But it solves a constraint of using Promise chains while needing to use multiple variables resolved from one step of a Promise chain in another, without creating too much mess.

Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

**If you write Javascript without semicolons**, then the 'assignment without declaration' syntax should be preceded with a semicolon for it to work predictably

```js
let a, b

;({a, b} = objectReturningFunction()) // <-- note the preceding ;
```

Just wanted to highlight this as it caught me out, and hopefully can save others some time figuring out why it doesn't work and/or produces weird results with code formatters like `prettier`.

Indeed, it's actually right there in the accepted answer (last line of the quoted docs) but easy to miss, especially without seeing an example!

Comment: Yeah.  A reason for people to use semi-colons!

Answer (score 18):

### Consider:

```
colors = { r: 204, g: 51, b: 102, hex: "#cc3366" };
```

### Here's a gist of some of the ways of destructuring:

Destructuring to **new** variables

```
let { r, g, b } = colors;
// initializes variables r, g, b
```

Destructuring to **new** variables with **different** names

```
let { r: red, g: green, b: blue } = colors;
// initializes variables red, green, blue
```

Destructuring to **existing** variables

```
let r, g, b;
...
({ r, g, b } = colors);
```

Destructuring to **existing** variables with **different** names

```
let red, green, blue;
...
({ r: red, g: green, b: blue } = colors);
```

Destructuring into another object with **same** property names

```
let myColor = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
...
({ r: myColor.r, g: myColor.g, b: myColor.b } = colors);
```

Destructuring into another object with **different** property names

```
let myColor = { red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 };
...
({ r: myColor.red, g: myColor.green, b: myColor.blue } = colors);
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's another way:

```
let {} = {a, b} = objectReturningFunction()
```

Pros:

- No parenthesis needed
- No semicolons needed
- The extra assignment is a guaranteed no-op (given that no weird things are going on - also, your transpiler might not realize this)

Cons:

- Looks a bit weird, although in my opinion no weirder than the `!(){...}()` [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression).
- Might be confusing as to why it's there. It is guaranteed to throw people off on the first encounter, so I would advise against using it as a one-off.

Comment: Kind of feels like IIFE's are more comparable to `;({ a, b })` than `let {} = { ... }`. Nice trick though. :)

Comment: @proto-n, +1, very smart idea. How did you came across this?

Comment: It's also possible to `let a, b; const { c } = { a, b } = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };`, combining declaration and reassignment in the same expression. `const` can be `var`, `let`, or `const` as preferred. In Typescript, the variables can be typed according to need as well, and the compiler will catch any invalid type assignments.

Comment: Hm sorry, im confused. How does c = 3 in your example? It seems like c is assigned the destructured values `{ a, b }`?