# How to destructure an object to an already defined variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following produces a syntax error:

```js
let source,
    screenings,
    size;

source = {
    screenings: 'a',
    size: 'b'
};

{
    screenings,
    size
} = source;
```

Expected result:

```
screenings should be equal to 'a'
size should be equal to 'b'
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71492680/979621) for a gist of the ways of applying destructuring to existing variables or existing objects.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

You need to use [assignment separate from declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assignment_separate_from_declaration_2) syntax:

```
({
    screenings,
    size
} = source);
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20source%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20screenings%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Asource%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20screenings%3A%20%27a%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20size%3A%20%27b%27%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A(%7B%20screenings%2C%20size%20%7D%20%3D%20source)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(screenings%2C%20size)%3B)

From the linked docs:

> The ( .. ) around the assignment statement is required syntax when
> using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration

And obviously you need to use this as you can't redeclare a `let` variable. If you were using `var`, you could just redeclare `var { screenings, size } = source;`

Comment: As I also posted [in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068605/1082449) this syntax needs to be preceded by a semicolon if you *don't* write JS with semicolons - i.e. `;({ screenings, size } = source)`