# in ES6 how can I destructure and assign an object to already defined variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am just starting to write in ES6 after years of rigidity sticking to plain ole JS (ES5). One feature that I really like is Object Destructuring while declaring and assigning variables :

```
function someFunction() {
    return Promise.resolve({
        a: 0,
        b: 1
    });
}
let {a, b} = await someFunction();
```

But there is a particular case where I'd love to transform existing variables like this :

```
function otherFunction(a, b) {
    return Promise.resolve({
        a: a + 1,
        b: b + 2
    });
}

let {a, b} = await someFunction();
{a, b} = await otherFunction(a, b);
```

Since the two variables were already declared using `let` I can't redeclare them. If I switch back to using `var` instead of let, I can do that :

```
var {a, b} = await someFunction();
var {a, b} = await otherFunction(a, b);
```

Which works perfectly fine but I want to benefit from the strictness of ES6 and the `let` keyword, is there a way to destructure-assign without declaring ?

Comment: Notice that you can also do `const {a: newA, b: newB} = …`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is reassign `a` and `b` that have already been assigned on the previous line so without re-using `let` let alone `const` since it's definitely a variable I want (some identified which value is bound to change).

Comment: The answer you have marked answers my question well but I couldn't find it before asking. Should I delete my question or keep it for future reference ?

Comment: You can keep it up, nothing wrong with it. (Admittedly, maybe you should have found the very similarly titled [How to destruct an object to an already defined variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32138513/1048572))

Comment: Wow weird that it wasn't suggested in the quick search before asking my question ! Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe because you used the correct term "destructure", not just "destruct". Let's hope your question will be found in the search from now on!