# Is it possible to destructure to already-declared variables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, destructuring

The following TypeScript works:

```
const carsAndTrucks = { cars: [], trucks: [] };
const { cars, trucks } = mapDealerInventory();

carsAndTrucks.cars = cars
carsAndTrucks.trucks = trucks

console.log(carsAndTrucks)

function mapDealerInventory() {
    return {cars: [1,2], trucks:['a', 'b']}
}
```

But is there a way to avoid having to set new variables just to destructure the return value of `mapDealerInventory()`? I was hoping this was possible:

`{ carsAndTrucks.cars, carsAndTrucks.trucks } = mapDealerInventory()`
but it gives the error "Unexpected token ="

So if you declare an object with its property types first, what's the cleanest way to set those properties from a function that returns their values in an object (or an array)?

Comment: If `carsAndTrucks` only has `cars` and `trucks`, why destructure at all? Might be easier to just reassign

Comment: `Object.assign(carsAndTrucks, mapDealerInventory())`

Comment: Well, I simplified a bit. In this case, carsAndTrucks actually has more properties than just those two.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

`({ cars, trucks } = carsAndTrucks)`

PLs see this answer as well

[How to destructure an object to an already defined variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138513/how-to-destructure-an-object-to-an-already-defined-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to set multiple fields on an object:

```
const { cars, trucks } = mapDealerInventory();
Object.assign(carsAndTrucks, { cars, trucks });
```

Or, if you don't need `cars` and `trucks` variables for anything else and `mapDealerInventory()` returns only these two fields:

```
Object.assign(carsAndTrucks, mapDealerInventory());
```

`carsAndTrucks` will retain all other properties, and `cars` and `trucks` will be changed.