# Object destructuring solution for long arrays?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Looking at this code:

```js
let lecture = {
  id: 2,
  title: "MyTitle",
  topics: [
    {
      title: "John",
      age: 1
    },
    {
      title: "John2",
      age: 2
    },
    {
      title: "John3",
      age: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the main `title` property and the third `age` in the array (via object destructuring)

[*I can do it via*](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=let%20lecture%20%3D%20%7B%0Aid%3A2%20%2C%20%0Atitle%3A%22MyTitle%22%2C%0Atopics%3A%5B%7Btitle%3A%22John%22%20%2C%20age%3A1%7D%2C%7Btitle%3A%22John2%22%20%2C%20age%3A2%7D%2C%7Btitle%3A%22John3%22%20%2C%20age%3A3%7D%5D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Alet%20%7B%20title%3AlectureTitle%20%2C%20topics%3A%5B%2C%2C%7Bage%3AthirdAge%7D%5D%7D%20%3D%20lecture%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(lectureTitle%2CthirdAge)) :

```js
let { title:lectureTitle , topics:[,,{age:thirdAge}]} = lecture;
console.log(lectureTitle,thirdAge);//MyTitle 3
```

**Question**

But what if the array has 100 items and I want the 99'th `age` ?

How would then I do it ?  Does object destructuring offer a solution for that?

Comment: Destructuring does not seem like a good fit for what you want to do. Unless you are dead set on it, why not just access at the indexes you want?

Comment: Nick , in order for me to know when should  i use stuff , i got to know their power and limitations . It's a learning purpose ( object destructering)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Clearly this is not a good fit for destructuring. When the alternative is cleaner code (in this case, good old-fashioned array access), you're probably better off not being clever.

Comment: In order to use array destructuring you should know exactly which array element you want to extract (namely its index), and you should know it at coding-time (not at run-time). It's a common case when you're dealing with small static arrays. But large arrays are seldom static, so situation like that seems extremely unlikely to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But what if the array has 100 items and I want the 99'th age ?

Arrays are objects, so this will do:

```
let {title: lectureTitle, topics: {98: {age: thirdAge}}} = lecture;
```

---

**Note** however that the `[...]` type of destructuring works with any iterable, whereas `{...}` only works with objects (and therefore arrays). For the above solution to work with arbitrary iterables you will have to spread the iterable and wrap it with an array.

```
let {title: lectureTitle, topics: {98: {age: thirdAge}}} = [...lecture];
```

Comment: But how to set value for a variable that already exists ? `let item = 'x'; [,item] = array` works but `let item = 'x'; { 1: item } = array` doesn't work since it doesn't have const or let keyword.

Comment: @YohanDahmani: You need to wrap the assignment in parenthesis. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/218196

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late to reply this,

```
const index = 65
const {title: lectureTitle, topics: {[index]: {age: thirdAge}}} = lecture
```

because in real life we normally would be using dynamic indices for arrays to destructure, `square brackets` instead of `numbers` or just `{ index: {age}}` doesn't work.