# Destructuring array get second value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to get array using destructing?

```
const num = [1,2,3,4,5];
const [ first ] = num; //1
```

`console.log(first)` I'm able to get 1, but when I try to do `const [ null, second ] = num` it has expected token error. How to get 2nd item of num array?

Answer (score 140):

You can skip parametr name just by putting comma

```
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var [ ,x] = num;
```

for more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values
section **Ignoring some returned values**

Comment: How to assign the full array to a new value? E.g., `const [x, y :as pos] = queue.shift();` (where `x` would be 1, `y` would be 2 and `pos` would be `[1, 2]`? (Only `:as` does not exist in Javascript)

Answer (score 46):

As alternative you can use *object destructuring* because arrays are objects:

```
var {1: second} = num;
```

But simply omitting the first element as Piotr suggests in their answer is a bit cleaner in this particular case.

See also [Object destructuring solution for long arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33397430/218196)