# How can I ignore certain returned values from array destructuring?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

Can I avoid declaring a useless variable when array destructuring when I am only interested in array values beyond index 0?

In the following, I want to avoid declaring `a`, I am only interested in index 1 and beyond.

```js
// How can I avoid declaring "a"?
const [a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(a, b, rest);
```

Comment: Related: [Destructuring array get second value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44559964/218196), [Object destructuring solution for long arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33397430/218196)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructuring array get second value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559964/destructuring-array-get-second-value)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

> Can I avoid declaring a useless variable when array destructuring when I am only interested in array values beyond index 0?

Yes, if you leave the first index of your assignment empty, nothing will be assigned. This behavior is [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values).

```js
// The first value in array will not be assigned
const [, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(b, rest);
```

You can use as many commas as you like wherever you like, except after a rest element:

```js
const [, , three] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(three);

const [, two, , four] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(two, four);
```

The following produces an error:

```js
const [, ...rest,] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: Is it possible to ignore all items at the front and keep only a fixed bunch at the end? Something like `const [..., fourth_to_last, , penultimate, last] = my_list;`

Comment: @BallpointBen, that's an interesting question. Unfortunately, rest elements must be the last element. A simple way to get the last items instead would be to reverse the array and vars: `const [last, penultimate, , fourth_to_last] = my_list.reverse();`

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring some returned values

You can use ',' ignore return values that you're not interested in:

```
const [, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(b);
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: This doesn't really add much that isn't covered by the existing answer.