# Typescript lint "no-unused-vars" with declared tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples, eslint, tslint

I have a line in code that looks like this:

```
const [full, text, url] = markdownLink.exec(match) || [null, null, '']
```

However I am not using `full` and the linter is giving me a warning.

> Line 28:  'full' is assigned a value but never used

I'd like to declare the tuple like this, but I don't need `full`. Is there a syntactical way to fix this by skipping full?

Comment: does `const [, text, url] = ...` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ignore certain returned values from array destructuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775128/how-can-i-ignore-certain-returned-values-from-array-destructuring)

Answer (score 10):

please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values

`const [, a, b] = arr`

Answer (score 0):

This warning is because your array destructuring is doing some affectations like `full = null;` which is not used later.

Array destructuring is quite sexy, but not always the solution. In your case simply access to the array in a classic way.

```js
const arr = markdownLink.exec(match) || [null, null, ''];
const text = arr[1];
const url = arr[2];
```