# JavaScript - Filter Object from criteria array, by deeply nested object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been breaking my head the last few days trying to implement the following functionality:

I have an incoming object, with a nested sub-object that's a list of dates. I would like to filter the original object against a range of dates, and return the modified filtered object, with only the specified dates.

Here is the desired functionality:

```
let incomingObject = {
    'one': {
        id: "one",
        dates: {
            "2021-05-01": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }],
            "2021-05-02": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }] } },
    'two': {
        id: "two",
        dates: {
            "2021-05-01": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }, { a: "foo2", b: "bar2" }],
            "2021-05-02": [{ a: "baz", b: "far" }] } },
    'three': {
        id: "three",
        dates: {
            "2021-05-03": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }],
            "2021-05-02": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }] } } };

// Function to get an array between two dates
const getDaysArray = function (s, e) {
    for (var a = [], d = new Date(s); d <= new Date(e); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        a.push(new Date(d));
    }
    let aStrings = a.map((date) => date.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
    return aStrings;
};
```

I have no idea how to implement this function, that would return the "filtered" object:

```
filterResults(incomingObject, getDaysArray("2021-05-01", "2021-05-01"));
```

This is the desired result - all the (sub-)objects that don't pass the
filter, are left out:

```
let desiredResult = {
    'one': {
        id: "one",
        dates: {
            "2021-05-01": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }] } },
    'two': {
        id: "two",
        dates: {
            "2021-05-01": [{ a: "foo", b: "bar" }, { a: "foo2", b: "bar2" }] } } };
```

And my progress so far:

```
let dateRange = getDaysArray("2021-05-01", "2021-05-01");

// This logs out only the required keys –– however, logging out the whole "parent" object is completely beyond my comprehension at the moment...
const filteredImages = Object.keys(images).forEach((key) => {
    let imgObject = images[key];
    Object.keys(images[key].dates).forEach((key) => {
        if (dateRange.includes(key)) {
            console.log(key);
        }
    });
});
```

All help or pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one? I find it very concise and modern:

```
const filterResults = (data, days) => 
  Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [n, { id, dates }]) => {
    const ds = Object.entries(dates).filter(([d,]) => days.includes(d))
    return ds.length ? { ...acc, [n]: { id, dates: Object.fromEntries(ds) } } : acc
  }, {})
```

The nice thing here is to use nested destructuring patterns and spread operator to avoid boilerplate code.

Also, while doing `reduce` over `Object.entries`, we can construct an object directly, without need of an intermediary array. In this implementation, everything is done in just one iteration over the original `data` array, so it performs better.

---

Additional information on the techniques used in the snippet:

- [Lambda syntax for anonymous function (arrow function `=>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions);

  ```
  const filterResults = (data, days) =>
  ```
- [`Object.entries()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries);
- [`Array.reduce()`, using empty object `{}` as initial accumulator](https://vmarchesin.medium.com/using-array-prototype-reduce-in-objects-using-javascript-dfcdae538fc8);
- [Array and Object nested argument destructuring `[a, { b, c }]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment);

  ```
  Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [n, { id, dates }]) => {
  ```
- [`Array.filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);
- [`Array.includes` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes);
- [Ignoring some values with Array destructuring `[d,]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775128/how-can-i-ignore-certain-returned-values-from-array-destructuring);

  ```
  const ds = Object.entries(dates).filter(([d,]) => days.includes(d))
  ```
- [Conditional ternary operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator);
- [Spread operator for object literals `{ ...acc }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals);
- [Computed property name `[n]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names);
- [`Object.fromEntries` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

  ```
  return ds.length ? { ...acc, [n]: { id, dates: Object.fromEntries(ds) } } : acc
  ```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you so much for sharing it! it is beyond my current comprehension –– I would like to understand it -- if you would have the time to share a commented-version of the steps, that would be very benefitial for my learning...

Comment: @DmnkVD, Added useful links on every technique used in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const incomingObject={one:{id:"one",dates:{"2021-05-01":[{a:"foo",b:"bar"}],"2021-05-02":[{a:"foo",b:"bar"}]}},two:{id:"two",dates:{"2021-05-01":[{a:"foo",b:"bar"},{a:"foo2",b:"bar2"}],"2021-05-02":[{a:"baz",b:"far"}]}},three:{id:"three",dates:{"2021-05-03":[{a:"foo",b:"bar"}],"2021-05-02":[{a:"foo",b:"bar"}]}}};
const getDaysArray = function(e,t){for(var a=[],n=new Date(e);n<=new Date(t);n.setDate(n.getDate()+1))a.push(new Date(n));return a.map(e=>e.toISOString().slice(0,10))}

const filterResults = (data, days) => Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [k, v]) => {
  const {dates, ...rest} = v
  const filteredDates = days.reduce((acc, date) => {
    if(v.dates[date]) acc[date] = v.dates[date]
    return acc
  }, {})
  if (Object.keys(filteredDates).length) 
    result.push([k, { ...rest, dates: filteredDates }])
  return result
}, [])

const res = filterResults(
  incomingObject,
  getDaysArray("2021-05-01", "2021-05-01")
)

console.log(Object.fromEntries(res))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array methods [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

In your case it could look something like this:

```js
const incoming = [
  { 
    nested: {
      date: '2021-05-01'
    }
  },
  { 
    nested: {
      date: '2021-03-16'
    }
  },
  { 
    nested: {
      date: '2021-02-05'
    }
  },
  { 
    nested: {
      date: '2021-01-20'
    }
  },
]

let someRange = ['2021-02-05', '2021-03-24']

const result = incoming.filter((item) => {
  return item.nested.date >= someRange[0] && item.nested.date <= someRange[1]
})

console.log(result)
```

You need to transform your object into an array with [`Object.values(yourArray)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

**EDIT:**

Just read your post again. You can use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve the keys from your object like so:

```js
const dates = {
  "2021-05-01": [{
      a: "foo",
      b: "bar",
    },
    {
      a: "foo2",
      b: "bar2",
    },
  ],
  "2021-05-02": [{
    a: "baz",
    b: "far",
  }, ],
}

const dateKeys = Object.keys(dates)

console.log(`Keys from date object: ${dateKeys}`)

const result = dateKeys.filter((item) => {
  return item >= '2021-05-02'
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! – the only problem in my case is that my keys are named as dates, e.g. `"2021-05-02": {}`, rather than `"date": "2021-05-02"`...