# How to get only one set state function from use state or some other hook React JS,

Tags: reactjs

I am using `const [cookie, setCookie] = useCookies(["user_token"])` cookies, I only want to use **setCookie** and not use **cookie** variable. and tslint is crashing build for unused cookie. how can I get only one **setCookie** or pass this issue.

Comment: if not using the variable why defining it in state for the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of react hook you mentioned is a simple array, you can look at it as an array too.

```js
const setCookie = useCookies(["user_token"])[1]

const [_, setCookie] = useCookies(["user_token"])
```

###### If you want to take this action a lot

For getting inspired, you can also take a look at package [`use-st8`](https://github.com/mweststrate/use-st8) which they bind `this` to return value, make different access action based on passed arguments

```js
const count = useSt8(0)
// get the current state
count() 
// change the state with to the given value
count(5)
```

Comment: `const [_, setCookie] = useCookies(["user_token"])` I believe `_` is a normal var name in JS, and linters will probably complaing about it as well.

Comment: I think any parameter name starting with _ is exempt from the check. but you can also disable the check for the line or hole project if configs are more strict

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing here is called "deconstructing", and it is possible to ignore first element like this:

```
[, setCookie] = useCookies(["user_token"])
```

See this answer for more explanation: [Destructuring array get second value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559964/destructuring-array-get-second-value)

Answer (score 2):

> ...or pass this issue.

Add this line just before the line which causes the error:

```
  /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
```