# Array Destructuring Skipping Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring, airbnb-js-styleguide

My [airbnb styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) told me I should use *Array Destructuring* for the assignment below.

```
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const result = splittedArr[1];
```

So I wrote it like this using skipping values *,* to get the second element.

```
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const [, result] = splittedArr;
```

```js
const splittedArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const result = splittedArr[1];

const [, res] = splittedArr;

console.log(result, res);
```

But for instance when I have a higher indice to destruct

```
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const result = splittedArr[5];
```

This would mean I have to write it like

```
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const [,,,, result] = splittedArr;
```

```js
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const result = splittedArr[4];

const [, , , , res] = splittedArr;

console.log(result, res);
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to write *Array Destructuring* with *skipping values* in JavaScript?

Comment: That's a guideline not a fixed rule. Have a look at the issues for that part of the guide (e.g. [Why use prefer-destructuring on arrays? #1791](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1791))

Comment: Please use common sense. It's far uglier to do `[,,,,,myvar] = ar` than `const myvar = ar[5]` and any style guide that tells you otherwise is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object destructuring solution for long arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397430/object-destructuring-solution-for-long-arrays)

Comment: My question is about Array Destructuring and not Object destructuring as you can see in my title and the title of your prodivded question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could treat the array as object and destructure with the index as key and [assign to a new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

```js
const
    array = [37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
    { 5: result } = array;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `object-destructuring` instead:

```js
const splittedArr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const { 1: second, 4: fifth } = splittedArr;

console.log(second, fifth);
```