# How to use array destructuring on Javascript array with index of not 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have the following variables:

```
$firstSection = $main.children[0];
$secondSection = $main.children[1];
```

To use array destructuring on the first variable, I can do this: `[$firstSection] = $main.children;`

However, how am I supposed to use array destructuring on the second variable? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Destructuring Skipping Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967014/array-destructuring-skipping-values)

Comment: Using `$` in JavaScript variables isn't really necessary nor advised.

Comment: The reason why I'm using it here is because it's a part of the JS Styleguide that I'm currently working with. Why do you think it's not advised? @tadman

Comment: That's a very strange style guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the second item to destructure to the right of the first, in a comma-separated list. It looks very similar to when declaring an array with 2 items.

```
const [$firstSection, $secondSection] = $main.children;
```

Answer (score 1):

The values are accessed through a comma separated list, so:

```
 const [$firstSection, $secondSection] = $main.children; 
 console.log($secondSection); // The second value in the $main.children array
```

And if you actually don't need the first value in the array, for whatever reason - you can actually just use a comma to omit the first value.

```
const [, $secondSection] = $main.children;
console.log($secondSection); // The second value in the $main.children array
```