# Destructuring values from object of the first index of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I replace accessing the temp variable values from the following code extract? I have tried to get all values through the default JS code, however, I would like to use destructuring here

```js
const temp = context.options[0]; // <----- here
const avoidPattern = [
    'foo', 'bar', 'abc', 'value', 'temp', 'num'
];


return [...avoidPattern, ...temp]
```

Comment: If you mean using destructuring to access the first element of a list: `const [temp, ...rest] = context.options;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can also be possible if we destructure `object` and `array` at the same time.

```js
const context = { options: [1, 2, 3] };
const { options: [temp] } = context;

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use this

```js
const context = { options: [1,2,3] }
const [temp] = context.options;

console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destructure the first element out of the `options` array.

1. You can first destructure the `options` property from the `context` object.
2. Then you can destructure the first item from the `options` array.

```js
const context = { options: [1, 2, 3] };

// Destucture the options key property
const {options} = context
console.log(options) // [1,2,3]

// Next, destructure the first item from the array
const [first] = options
console.log(first) // 1
```

You can also combine the two steps mentioned above using the colon `:` operator, which is used to provide an alias while destructing an object.

```js
const context = { options: [1, 2, 3] };

// Destucture the options property 
// and in the alias destructure the first item of the array
const {options: [first]} = context
console.log(first) // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr=['data','title','image']; 

let [first]=arr[1];

console.log(first);
```

Comment: `arr[1]` will be `title` and when you destructure it will give you the first character from it `t`

Comment: yes! as in question he requiresshow data on  index so i write my code arr[1] as first instead of first you can write second let arr=['data','title','image']; 

let [second]=arr[1];

console.log(second);

Answer (score 0):

An interesting that *Array in JavaScript is an object,* So you can destructure an array as object like this

```js
const context = { options: [1, 2, 3] };
const { options } = context; // [1, 2, 3]
const {0:firstItem } = options;
console.log(firstItem);
```

As you can see, key of `options` array is `integer` number. Actually, it's index. In this way, you can destructure an array with the long array by index in the that way.

More details here: [Object destructuring solution for long arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397430/object-destructuring-solution-for-long-arrays)