# Multiple declarations of same variable name with object destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this situation where I want to use the same variable name multiple times with object desctructuring:

```
let {body, response} = await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/whitelist`, headers);
let parsedBody = await siamese.parse(body);
assert(parsedBody.success, 'response body should have a success property.');
assert(parsedBody.success.length === usernames.length, 'wrong number of items in response body array.');
let {body, response} = await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/caches/whitelist`, headers);
let parsedBody = await siamese.parse(body);
```

but when I run the script with node, node will complain before runtime:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'body' has already been declared
```

there are two problems which prevent me from getting an easy solution:

1. I can't do this with object destructuring:

   `let {a,b} = c;`
      `{a,b} = c;  // not allowed`
2. I can't rename `body` or `response`, because this is what is returned by the call.

What should I do?

Maybe the best thing to do is something like:

```
let {body,response} = ...
let {body:body1, response:resp1} = ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't do this with object destructuring: `{a,b} = c;`

You can, you just need to [put it in parenthesis to be syntactically valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572):

```
({a, b} = c);
```

> Maybe the best thing to do is something like `let {body:body2, response:resp2} = …`

Yes, that's the best solution indeed. You might even want to use `const` instead of `let`.

> What should I do?

Another solution, which I wouldn't necessarily recommend but just want to mention for completeness, is to introduce separate scopes for the variables:

```
{
  let {body, response} = await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/whitelist`, headers);
  let parsedBody = await siamese.parse(body);
  assert(parsedBody.success, 'response body should have a success property.');
  assert(parsedBody.success.length === usernames.length, 'wrong number of items in response body array.');
}
{
  let {body, response} = await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/caches/whitelist`, headers);
  let parsedBody = await siamese.parse(body);
}
```

And of course you can also just use `var` instead of `let`, which doesn't bitch about redeclarations.

Comment: The error is caused by using `let` again to declare a variable by the same name. If you want to reuse body, either use `var` or drop the `let` and use nothing the second time.

Comment: @chris I thought it was understood by the OP what's causing the error, so I didn't mention it again

Comment: I think block scope is probably the cleanest way to do this, or using var instead of let.

Comment: great answer by the way (to a great question ;)