# how to destruct part of properties from an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, I got an object like this:

```
obj1 = {
     name: 'Bob',
     age:  20,
     career: 'teacher'
  }
```

Now I need to duplicate part of its properties instead all of them.

```
obj2 = {
     name: '',
     age: '',
  }
```

I know I can do it like `obj2.name = obj1.name`, which will be verbose if many properties need to be duplicated. Are there any other quick ways to solve this problem?
I tried

`let {name: obj2.name, age: obj2.age} = obj1;`

but got error.

Comment: you could use a white list for properties, or a black list. then iterate.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Take a look at [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you don't need object destructuring, just simple assignment:

```
obj2 = { name: obj1.name, age: obj1.age }
```

Now, `obj2` holds wanted properties:

```
console.log(obj2);
// Prints {name: "Bob", age: 20}
```

---

If you want to merge old properties of `obj2` with new ones, you could do:

```
obj2 = { ...obj2, name: obj1.name, age: obj1.age }
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `let` (you're not declaring variables) and [surround with parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572):

```
({name: obj2.name, age: obj2.age} = obj1);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, it should be `(obj1 = {name: obj2.name, age: obj2.age});`

Comment: It works! Would you please explain why or what the parentheses did.

Comment: @Bellian It's destructuring without `let`

Comment: @xiaojieLuo See the link that explains why the parentheses are necessary

Comment: I see. I forgot to init the obj2. that makes sense!

Comment: @Bergi no, it doesn't [https://jsfiddle.net/m9692mg6/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/m9692mg6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use ES6 Object destructuring syntax

```
   var obj = { name: 'kailash', age: 25, des: 'backenddev'}
   ({name} = obj);
```

Comment: That assigns to a global `name` variable?

Comment: yeah it does assign to global name var

Comment: Yes - don't do that :-)

Comment: I thought obj destructing was as similar to array but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the target object as template for the properties and assign the values of `obj1` with a default value of the target object.

```js
var obj1 = { name: 'Bob', age:  20, career: 'teacher' },
    obj2 = { name: '', age: '' };
    
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => obj2[k] = obj1[k] || obj2[k]);

console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to write a reuable method for this. You can supply an object and the methods you would like to copy.

```
const duplicatePropertiesFromObject = (obj, propertyNames = [], newObj = {}) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (propertyNames.includes(key)) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return newObj;
}
```