# ES6 goodies for destructuring and assigning to object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am a software developer who is now **learning the new ES6 style of JavaScript**. I find the ES6 features great, but I'm still not aware of all the most popular features that ES6 offers and I find it difficult to use it wisely in practice.

I have the following line of code that - if possible and practical - I'd like to make simpler. I have to admit that in this example, I would also be *refactoring just for the sake of refactoring* and learning better how ES6 can help me creating expressive, simple code in the future (or at least understand if someone uses some crazy one-liner).

```
// HTML: <canvas></canvas>
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// I'm wondering if there is another way to do this:
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

I could create `width` and `height` like this:

```
const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
// equivalent to:
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;
```

*I am looking for a solution that rather than creating new variables, assigns the values to an object, using some property names.* **Is there an idiomatic way to do this?**

Something like this:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// NONE OF THESE WORKED
const { innerWidth: canvas.width, innerHeight: canvas.height } = window;
const { canvas.width, canvas.height } = { window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Something like this:
>
> ```
> // NONE OF THESE WORKED
> const { innerWidth: canvas.width, innerHeight: canvas.height } = window;
> ```

This is the right approach. However, you don't want to declare new variables but instead have the `canvas` properties as targets, so `const` is wrong here. You need only the assignment. And [you need to wrap in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572):

```
({ innerWidth: canvas.width, innerHeight: canvas.height } = window);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this in one line is using [**Array destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). The example below considers that the property names are different on the source and destination object.

```
[canvas.width, canvas.height] = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
```

In my opinion, this is pretty intuitive code, but I don't see it used often. It might cause some confusion amongst less-experienced JavaScript developers, so you need to make your own decision whether it actually improves the readability of your code.

Comment: That's not really any better than two separate statements. I don't think it's clean, rather unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I rephrased it to make clear that it's not necessarily the best option, but an option nonetheless.

Comment: That’s a matter of habituation. If you’re used to this structure and understand it well, it’s intuitively understandable from a single look. Particularly for pairs like width/height or x/y, it’s clean and short, and certainly not “extremely unreadable”.