# Eslint - Prefer Object destructing (prefer destructing)

Tags: node.js, eslint, lint

In my nodejs script for webdriverio, I declared like below :

```
let name;
name = feature.children[0].name;
```

But then I am getting lint error :

```
Prefer Object destructing (prefer destructing)
```

Not sure whats this error. Can you please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this error, but I think it's telling you to prefer object **destructuring**.

You can find more about this error here : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring

Here's how to fix it :

```
let { name } = feature.children[0];
```

Comment: Or perhaps it's looking for `let [{ name }] = feature.children;`, though that isn't so readable

Comment: But how can I add it in 2 lines ? Means I want to use name as a global variable. @CertainPerformance

Comment: @max See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/object-destructuring-without-var

Comment: @max What do you mean, the first answer on the question I linked shows you how to do it?