# destructuring ecmascript es7

Tags: javascript, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

Is there a way to simplify the following code?

```
let { page_size, current_page } = paging;

this.p_start = page_size * current_page;
this.p_current = current_page;
this.p_dg_current = this.p_current + 1;
this.p_size = page_size;
```

`paging` is an object and has properties `page_size` and `current_page`.

Is there a destructing way to assign the paging.page_size and paging.current_page directly to this.p_size and this.p_current?

```
  let { this.p_size = page_size, this.p_current = current_page } = paging;

  this.p_start = page_size * current_page;
  this.p_dg_current = this.p_current + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for destructuring is `{ propertyName: targetExpression = default }`. You have the right idea though (and [you need to omit the `let`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572), as you're not declaring variables):

```
({ page_size: this.p_size, current_page: this.p_current } = paging);

this.p_start = this.p_size * this.p_current;
this.p_dg_current = this.p_current + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this way

```
 let { page_size: p_size, current_page: p_current } = paging;
        this.p_start = page_size * current_page;
        this.p_dg_current = this.p_current + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, instead of `paging1` use `this`

```js
let paging = {page_size : 10, current_page : 9};
let paging1 = {p_size : 0, c_size : 0};
({ page_size : paging1.p_size, current_page : paging1.c_size } = paging)

console.log(paging1.p_size+ ' '+ paging1.c_size)
```