# Simplified syntax for $: marks a statement as reactive

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

How to simplify `$:` code?:

`Symbol.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let symbol;
    $:c = symbol.c;
    $:name = symbol.name;
    $:{console.log("log Symbol", name, c)}
</script>
<div on:click={()=>symbol.c=0} >
    {name} {c}
</div>
```

I dream of something like:

```
export let symbol;
$:{c,name} = symbol;
```

I can't use...

```
export let c,name;
```

...because in `on:click` I have to modify the `symbol` object with `symbol.c = 0` - without this my `store` named `list` will not update.

The whole example: https://svelte.dev/repl/37e3a1fa96fc4f1dbc7cfcafb1edc439?version=3.22.1

**PS,** If you can use `export let c, name;` without losing the `store` update, please specify how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to destructure a variable in a reactive statement, simply wrap the statement in parentheses:

`$: ({ c, name } = symbol);`

Learn more here: [object destructuring without var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/object-destructuring-without-var)

Answer (score 1):

As it stands now, you're currently *not* updating your `list` store in your `on:click` handler. In fact, you have no method to set/update your `list` store other than to initialize it or set an element to zero using an odd mechanism that relies on another store.

I honestly cannot make much sense of your store, but nonetheless, using the store as you have designed it and piggybacking on its existing methods, the following will work and *actually* update your store:

`Symbol.svelte`

```js
<script>
  import { list, inputSymbol } from './stores.js';
  export let c, name
  $:console.log("log Symbol", name, c)
</script>
<div on:click={() => {
  inputSymbol.set(name)
  list.setToZero()
}}>
  {name} {c}
</div>
```

`App.svelte`

```js
...
{#each $list as symbol (symbol.name)}
    <Symbol {...symbol}/>
{/each}
```

[See REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a273ad04cf4845d7a49b1280b3f8b73f?version=3.22.1) (added `list` store console log in App.svelte to actually track store updates)