# Javascript overwrite destructured let variable

Tags: javascript, destructuring

## Problem

Is it possible to overwrite multiple variables assigned with `let`

```
const somefunction = (data) => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data})

let {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(3)
```

Now, how can one overwrite {a, b, c, d} in one statement after calling someFunction with a different argument?

## Possible Solutions

#### Not working! (obviously)

```
const somefunction = (data) => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data})

let {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(3)
{a, b, c, d} = somefunction(5)
```

#### Working

This seems to work, but my prettier will remove the leading semicolon (+ the syntax is crazy)

```
const somefunction = (data) => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data})

let {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(3)
;({a, b, c, d} = somefunction(5))
```

are there other ways?

Comment: You need to wrap {} in () in an arrow function that has no brackets for grouping statements: `const somefunction = data => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data})`

Comment: Adding the semicolon and wrapping `()` is the [only way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/). You need to change prettier settings.

Comment: add manually an semicolon `let {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(3);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap {} in () in an arrow function that has no brackets for grouping statements:

```js
const somefunction = data => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data});

const {a,b,c,d} = somefunction(3)
console.log(a,b,c,d)
```

Or use {} and return

```js
const somefunction = data => {
  return {a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data}
};

const {a,b,c,d} = somefunction(3)
console.log(a,b,c,d)
```

Overwrite using let:

```js
const somefunction = data => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data});

let {a,b,c,d} = somefunction(3);
console.log(a,b,c,d);

({a,b,c,d} = somefunction(5));

console.log(a,b,c,d);
```

Overwrite using var ( I wouldn't ;) )

```js
const somefunction = data => ({a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data});

var {a,b,c,d} = somefunction(3);
console.log(a,b,c,d);

var {a,b,c,d} = somefunction(5);

console.log(a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Ahh I see, had a typo oin the first formula. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/hfqg2oLa/

Comment: Perhaps we are not talking about the same thing?

Comment: Jupp, you are right. had a typo in the first formula. However, the question is about overwriting all the variables in one go.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but you can use `var` instead of `let`.

```js
const somefunction = (data) => {return {a:1+data, b:2-data, c: 2*data, d: 3+1*data}}

var {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(3)

console.log(a,b,c,d)

var {a, b, c, d} = somefunction(4)

console.log(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: That is most certainly a solution. I was under the impression not to use var anymore. What are the drawbacks?

Comment: @FabianBosler The only drawback is that your declaration will be [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and it won't be block scoped.