# Why put an assignment statement in parentheses?

Tags: javascript

Referring to this page: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

In the code excerpt below, the first assignment statement is inside parentheses. Is there any benefit to doing that? I omitted them with no apparent loss of functionality, but wondering if I might be missing out on some desired behavior.

```
switch (req.get('content-type')) {
    // '{"name":"John"}'
    case 'application/json':
      ({name} = req.body);
      break;

    // 'John', stored in a Buffer
    case 'application/octet-stream':
      name = req.body.toString(); // Convert buffer to a string
      break;
```

Comment: its possible case blocks might start with a "{" which could be confusing to the compiler or to someone reading the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [object destructuring without var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/object-destructuring-without-var)

Comment: @user202729 That must be it because I used a "const" without even thinking (and without the const there is an error). Please post as an answer so I can accept. Thanks!