# Destruct and assign in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code

```
const myVariable: number | undefined;

if (someCondition) {
     const { someAttribute, anotherAttribute } = someFunction(); //here I want to assign directly that myVariable to someAttribute. 
     doAnotherTask(anotherAttribute);
  
}

doSomethingWithVariable(myVariable);
```

How can I destruct `someFunction` to get `someAttribute` and directly assign `myVariable` to it.

`const {someAttribute: myVariable}` wouldnt work here, since `myVariable` is defined outside the scope of the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the `const`, since you're not creating a new variable. And `myVariable` can't be a `const` since you need to assign a value to it later.

[Due to how the JavaScript language works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386370/12101554), you also need parentheses around the destructuring statement.

```
let myVariable: number | undefined;

if (someCondition) {
     ({ someAttribute: myVariable } = someFunction());
}

doSomethingWithVariable(myVariable);
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to declare a `let someAttibute`outside, otherwise you have a `var`

Comment: @mgm793 no, `someAttribute` is not used and not defined, it's just name of the property and not a variable

Comment: Note you need parentheses when trying to destructure to an existing variable: https://tsplay.dev/N7OdPN

Comment: What if I want to add another property from `someFunction` to the descrtruction and use it somewhere else? see my updated question.

Comment: @AngularDebutant you need to be defining _all_ or _none_ of the destructured variables.

Comment: @AngularDebutant If you want to use a property outside of the if-block scope, then you'll need to have a `let` variable declaration at the top and do the same thing. Alternatively you can use `var` with a second destructuring statement, though `var` would be seen as a codesmell since we're way past the introduction of `let` and `const`

Comment: @Samathingamajig what if I want to use the second property inside the if statement?

Comment: The you would either declare a new variable with `let` inside the `if` but before the destructuring, or you would store the direct value of the function call and perform two destructures.