# How can I clean up this destructuring assignment in js?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, destructuring

In Javascaript, I publicly assigned the variable A. I now want to assign A to a destructured variable. But all I can think of is:

const {variable} = getVariable(); 
A = variable;

How can I make this into a one-liner?

Comment: You can't assign to an already existing variable in a destructuring assignment. Maybe just don't use destructuring? `A = getVariable().variable`

Comment: @pascalpuetz [You actually could](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572), but indeed `A = getVariable().variable;` is the simplest and cleanest way to write this

Comment: @Bergi Oh wow, didn't realize that was possible. Thanks for sharing that link!

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
({variable: A} = getVariable());
```

if you insist on [using destructuring to assign a previously declared variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572), but really there's no good reason to use destructuring here. Normal property access is so much simpler, shorter, and more readable:

```
A = getVariable().variable;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
const {variable:A} = getVariable();
```

Comment: From the users example `A` seems to already be defined. Thats why it needs to be solved with an assignment pattern https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#binding_and_assignment just like in @Bergis example.